# Inventory management using QR code Application

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, qr-code

Problem statement: A mobile application is required that is capable of a.) Having all the details of the equipment like S/N, Date of Installation, etc. by scanning a QR code/ barcode. b.) Readily accessing the past service record by scanning a QR code/ barcode. c.) Entering the details and updating service history on the spot, just after maintenance.

Should this app have QR generation and printing facility?

Comment: Would you like to use Flutter?

Comment: And what is your question?